# post_class() breaks out of formatting. . . extra markup also generated

Tags: formatting, filters, post-class

Hoping Im just running into something easy

Here's the scenario, I've created a function called `tr_get_post_image_tplt` that spits out the post thumbnail (or custom size) for the post being called.

Im calling it as follows from my front-page loop:

```
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"<?php post_class('thumbnail span1'); ?> ><?php tr_get_post_image_tplt('thumbnail', 'thumbnail');?><a/>
```

I would expect the function to output something like:

```
<a href="/864/" class="post-864 post type-post status-publish format-quote hentry category-general thumbnail span1"><img src="/wp-content/themes/_tr_roots/img/post-thumb-default.gif" class="post-864 post type-post status-publish format-quote hentry category-general thumbnail" alt="something attachment"/><a/>
```

But instead Im getting:

```
<a href="/864/"class="post-864 post type-post status-publish format-quote hentry category-general thumbnail span1">class="post-864 post type-post status-publish format-quote hentry category-general thumbnail"<p><img src="/wp-content/themes/_tr_roots/img/post-thumb-default.gif"  alt="something attachment"/></p>
<a/>
```

Note that that the class has slipped out of the `<a>` tag and extra markup has been added.

I've poured over this for hours now - so Im praying its not some silly typo.

But assuming it isn't a typo can someone explain what's going on and how to avoid it in future?

Here's the function, stored in a functionality plugin(though I've tried it in functions.php with the same results):

```
function tr_get_post_image_tplt($size='thumbnail', $class='thumbnail', $default='post-thumb-default.gif') {
global $post;

if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { // check if the post has a Post Thumbnail assigned to it.
    $image_src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(), $size );

    $alt_text =  get_the_title(get_post_thumbnail_id());
    $tr_post_thumb = '<img src="' . $image_src[0] . '" ' . post_class($class) . ' alt="' . $alt_text . 'post" />';
    //$tr_post_thumb = the_post_thumbnail($size); isn't flexable enough
}
else{
    $photos = get_children( array(
    'post_parent' => $post->ID, 
    'post_status' => 'inherit', 
    'post_type' => 'attachment', 
    'post_mime_type' => 'image', 
    'order' => 'ASC', 
    'orderby' => 'menu_order ID'
    ) );
    if (!empty($photos)) {
        $photo = array_shift($photos);
        $image_src = wp_get_attachment_image_src($photo->ID, $size);
        $alt_text =  get_the_title($photo->ID);
        $tr_post_thumb = '<img src="' . $image_src[0] . '" ' . post_class($class) . '" alt="' . $alt_text . '" />';
    }
    else {
        // if above fails, spit out a default image
        $alt_text =  get_the_title($post->ID);
        $tr_post_thumb = '<img src="' . get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/img/' . $default . '" ' . post_class($class) . ' alt="' . $alt_text . ' attachment"/>';      
    }
}
echo apply_filters('the_content', $tr_post_thumb );
}
```

Many thanks for sharing your experience!

Answer (score 3):

Use `get_post_class()` when [you want the values to be returned](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_class) rather than echod.

Comment: @orionrush : The Codex is your friend, read the Codex :)

Comment: Thanks, but I went to the codex first, Im not being lazy here - honest. I wouldn't waste your time if the answer was evident (to me). 

My question still stands - In this use case post_class is exactly what I want - I want it to spit out `class="some list"` so why dosent it output where I've placed it in the markup? - what's gong on?

Otherwise we would use get_post_class() in all cases - no? I didn't use get_post_class() because I dont need to further process the array, which is as I understand, what it is for.

Comment: Further substituting `post_class()` with something like `'class="' . implode(get_post_class($class)) . '"` dosen't solve the added `<p>` elements which are being injected into the markup.

Comment: Ahh - http://wordpress.org/support/topic/prevent-wordpress-from-wrapping-p-tags-around-images
Even though the image is already contained in a div, WP dosen't know it - so it automatically wraps it in a `<p>` to make valid markup. Adding wrapping `<div>` tags to my function prevents this - though completely superfluous markup IMHO.  - I was conflating the two issues as they were appearing concurrently. Still would love to know *why* post_class() dosen't play nice.